# Django Rest Framework User Model Serializer Nested

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having some issues with my DRF Serializers. I essentially have a model that has Django users as Foreign keys so I can see who is attached to a job.

When I try and resolve these user ID's nested inside my Job serializer using a User serializer I only see the ID, but when I use the User serializer on it's own not nested I get the correct fields returned. Below is my code snippets. Any help would be great.

models.py

```
from profiles.models import UserProfile
class Job(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    designer_one = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='designer_one', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    designer_two = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='designer_two', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = "Job"
        verbose_name_plural = "Jobs"
        ordering = ['name']
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class JobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TasksSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    designer_one = UsersSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    designer_two = UsersSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'designer_one', 'designer_two', 'tasks')
```

What I get returned from UsersSerializer API View

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test@example.co.uk",
    "first_name": "Admin",
    "last_name": "User"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "test1@example.co.uk",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": ""
}
]
```

What I get returned from JobsSerializer API View

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test job",
    "designer_one": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "designer_two": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Task",
            "job": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Remove designer_one = UsersSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    designer_two = UsersSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)  from JobsSerializer. It should show, if not add depth=1 for JobsSerializer

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I removed those lines but all I am returned then is the ID as an int. I then added depth = 1 both with and without those lines and nothing changed.

Comment: Have then added `depth=1` in JobsSerializer. in `class Meta: `

Comment: @AnupYadav That worked, thanks a lot. I did need to make it `depth=2` to get the correct level though. Do you know if there is a way to limit what fields are returned? Ideally I don't want passwords and other information like that sent via the api

Comment: Great, I could help you, enjoy  :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `UsersSerializer` for model `User`, meanwhile `designer_one` and `designer_two` are of type `UserProfiile`.

You can allow DRF generate the nested serializers for you using the `depth` option as @Anup Yadav suggested but if you want to have control over which fields are displayed, you need to create your own serializer for `Userprofile` and use it in the Job serializer